# How to show array of images in my blade view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I want to show array of images in my blade view. I have a table which has some fields like name, address, images. where images are more than one how I can show multiple images in my blade-view.

```
 <div class="business-gallery">
                    <div class="gallery">
                        {{-- {{dd($business->image)}} --}}
                        {{-- @json($business->image) --}}
                        <img src="{{$business['image'][0]}}" alt="Second image" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

for each loop etc doesn't work for me like this,I can even fetch/show single image on my view

```
@foreach($business['image'] as $image)
  <image src="{{ $business['Name']}}" />
@endforeach
```

and my controller from where I save data to DB. there is no image model I am storing images directly to a business model

```
  // Business insertion from user side
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('pictures')) {
            foreach ($request->file('pictures') as $picture) {
                $pictures[] = $fileName = time() . $picture->getclientOriginalName();
                Storage::put('public/' . $fileName, file_get_contents($picture));
            }
            Business::create([
                'image' => implode(',', $pictures),
                'name' => $request->name,
                'price' => $request->input('price'),
                'description' => $request->input('description'),
                'user_id' => $request->input('user'),
                'category_id' => $request->input('category'),
                'subCategory_id' => $request->input('subCategory'),
                'province_id' => $request->input('province'),
                'city_id' => $request->input('city'),
            ]);
        }
        return redirect('sell-business-form')->with('success', 'Your business is under review, Please wait for confirmation');

 public function businessDetail($id)
    {
        $business = Business::findOrFail($id);
        return view('front-end.business-detail', compact('business'));
    }
```

please help me out

Comment: When you say "it is not working for you" what do you mean exactly? Are you getting any kind of errors? Are your image files saved somewhere?

Comment: For this to work your ```$business->image``` should contain an array of urls to your images (```['http://some-url.com/some-image.jpg', 'http://another-url.com/another-image.jpg']```). Is this the case?

Comment: your question is not clear. we want your related controller method code to answer this question. because then only we can find how to your are passing value to blade?

Comment: I'm assuming you have defined `Business` model and an `Image` model and relationships for those models.

```@foreach($business->image as $image)
        <img src="{{$image->url}}">// property of your Image model which contains the url of the image
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Otherwise if the `$business['image'][0]` works as intended then you do this:
```@foreach($business['image'] as $image)
<img src="{{$image}}">
@endforeach
```

It loops through the `$business['image']` array. It's not quite how laravel is intended to be used for situation like this, but it should work.

Comment: i update my question please check it out. i add controller method how i passing data to vie @Dev

Comment: @livresonltc check i update my post.

Comment: @user3647971 no i dont have image model. :)

Comment: @Maazktk You should first get the image files from the storage and attach those to your view. 
```$imagenames = explode(",",$business->images);
$images= array();
foreach($imagenames as $image){
    $images[] = Storage::get('public/'.$image);
}
//add $images to blade template
```

Comment: @Maazktk I just noticed that gets only the raw file contents and you need the urls right? Use `Storage::url('public/'.$image);` instead then. It creates the url for the specified file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach (explode('|', $business->image) as $images)
   <img style="width:30%;margin:10px;padding:10px" 
         src="/asset/images/{{$images}}">
                                        <br>
    @endforeach
```

**Try This Will Fix Your Problem**

> And Please Referee and read laravel naming i see some minor but
> incorrect naming for example if your image is array try to say images
> not image more referee laravel documentation